# ipython: pressing 'esc' key breaks readline

Tags: readline, ipython

In ipython, if I press 'esc' followed by 'enter' (and possibly other characters?), readline breaks.  I can no longer search through command history using the 'up' key, and some commands (e.g., control-K) fail.

Is there a way to reset readline within an ipython session?  What is going on when I press these keys?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The poster's suggested answer doesn't seem to work for me in iPython 0.12+. I can run:

```
get_ipython().init_readline()
```

but that doesn't seem to help.

However I noticed that I sometimes see similar problems in my iPython sessions. It appears that I had inadvertently switched from the default Emacs readline editing mode to vi-mode(vim-mode). According to the the [readline docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Readline-vi-Mode.html) to switch between them you are supposed to be able to use the M-C-j key combination but that only seems to allow me to switch to vi-mode. To switch back to Emacs mode one can use C-e but that didn't appear to work for me - I had to instead do M-C-e - on my Mac (where <kbd>ESC</kbd> is used as the 'Meta' key) it is: <kbd>ESC</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>

The contents of my ~/.inputrc is as follows:

```
set meta-flag on
set input-meta on
set convert-meta off
set output-meta on
```

Comment: I got similar problem: After misfortune series of keystrokes, emacs mode stopped working. ESC+CTRL+e did the trick to reset back to the Emacs mode. Ipython 1.2.1 on Linux x86_64.

Answer (score 2):

Got impatient.  Solution is:

```
IPython.InteractiveShell.init_readline(get_ipython())
```

Looks like this might be a known bug too: http://www.catonmat.net/blog/bash-vi-editing-mode-cheat-sheet/